# Extend Teamsite actions

Tags: content-management-system, teamsite, autonomy

I was wondering if it possible to extend Teamsite functionality? For example, I would like to add my own button under Actions -> MyAction which would perform my java based operation (update pages or something)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom menu actions you'll need to make modifications to

```
<iw-home>/local/config/lib/content_center/customer_src/etc/conf/customer/ui_custom.xml
```

There should be some examples in the file unless you've erased the contents. The basic format is as follows:

```
<action-list id="iw.ccpro.filesys.menubar">
    <menu id="iw.ccpro.action.menu">
        <link id="company.ccpro.list_directory.custMenuAction.link"
              label="Custom Action"
              description="Custom Action Description"                  
              url="/iw-bin/custom_menu_action.ipl"
              target="_blank"
              icon="/base/images/customIcon.gif"
         />
    </menu>
</action-list>
```

For a Java based operation you would just change the url to your servlet path.

For example:

```
url="<iw-hostname>/iw-cc/command/customJavaAction"
```